# Very slow site speed

Tags: database, speed

Most pages on our large site are taking far too long to load. I have gone through and made some template changes that have been suggested, and currently have been running rebuild search index for over 12 hours after having deselected multiple fields for being included in search (the task has got barely half-way... and I need to shut my computer to travel shortly).

If that's the only fix will keep trying, but am I somehow needlessly calling information as this shows?

[image]

Comment: Which Craft version is the site on?

Comment: Craft Pro 3.7.11

Comment: The index/home page, individual entry pages, and tag pages are all super slow - then all but one category pages are fine, and single entry pages similarly load quickly.

Have been trying to test different templates/permutations of calls with the web developer plugin, but can't seem to narrow anything down: it's as if one call is made, they're ALL made, somehow.

Comment: Have you checked your log files? What does it say there? Do you use the Neo Plugin?

Comment: No, we don't use that plugin, and what should I be looking for in the log files?

Comment: For errors, or tasks in the background which could cause the slow down.

Comment: Can you share some code for one of the slow page?

Comment: @EmmaSwann did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No. I made a template with the basic header/footer of the site - brought through Craft templates - and that loaded quickly. 

I then called information for one entry, and it was several seconds, with the toolbar citing a long list of fields.